# Extracting the contents of an HTMLInputElement with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a hidden element...

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.AllDates" id="hidData" name="hidData" />
```

which holds a generic list...

```
public List<ttDay> AllDates { get; set; }
```

of time table dates

```
public class ttDay
{
    public int ttID { get; set; }
    public int available { get; set; }
    public int booked { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }

    public ttDay(int Id, int Available, int Booked, DateTime Date, string Notes)
    {
        this.ttID = Id;
        this.available = Available;
        this.booked = Booked;
        this.date = Date;
        this.notes = Notes;
    }
}
```

The user selects a date via a DatePicker, and then I now need to be able to get the ID (ttID) associated with the date by locating the row in the hidden field.

Getting this value is what I am having problems with.
Via jQuery I can see that the hiData item holds the list, as

```
alert($('#hidData').val());
```

returns

```
System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MySite.Model.ttDay]
```

and

```
 var foo = document.getElementById('hidData');
```

returns

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

But I am not able to traverse the contents (at all!) to get what I want. Any help appreciated :)

**Update**

Following the very helpful comments (cheers DLeh and MikeSmithDev), I have changed the input definition to

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllDates)) " id="hidData" name="hidData" />
```

and am now at least getting hold of the json...

```
[
{"ttID":1,"available":10,"booked":10,"date":"\/Date(1426759200000)\/","notes":"sold out"},
{"ttID":2,"available":10,"booked":7, "date":"\/Date(1426845600000)\/","notes":""},
{"ttID":3,"available":10,"booked":3, "date":"\/Date(1426932000000)\/","notes":""},
{"ttID":4,"available":10,"booked":0, "date":"\/Date(1427018400000)\/","notes":""}
, ....
]
```

How do I extract the ttID of a specific date?

Comment: A C# `List<T>` cannot be directly translated to HTML, because it doesn't have a direct definition in HTML or Javascript. You need to transform it into json to get all the fields as a javascript object.

Comment: One option is to convert your list to a JSON string and pass that to your hidden field... then on the client side you can parse it back into JSON to manipulate.